# Usage telethon with redis

Tags: telethon

I can convert my TLObjects to json format. I want to use Redis with Telethon to cache my objects. But I can't find a way to convert TLObjects from json format. I can prepare the parent class if I find the ["_"] field of the json object. But child dicts are not converted to TLObjects. Maybe telethon has this function inside the project or other solutions?